# Guid property regenerating in WebApi POST call

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, guid, getter-setter

**The Guid stored in my entity is regenerating after I make a POST call to my WebApi controller.** Here is how it goes, I have the following entity(POCO):

```
     public class MyEntity : MyBaseEntity
        {
         public virtual int  Prop1{ get; set;}
         private string _ID;
         public virtual string ID { 
          get {
            if(_ID == null) { 
             _ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); 
             return _ID;
            }
            else { 
             return _ID; 
            }
         } 
         set {
          _ID = value;
         } 
       } //End ID property
     } //End Entity
```

The entity has a property named **ID**. I do some work on my controller and return a `List<MyEntity>` to the MVVM front end which is loaded in the `Kendo Grid`. The `List<MyEntity>` contains newly generated GUIDs in the ID property. Now user edits a row of the grid which results in an **AJAX POST** call back to my WebApi controller which has a POST parameter `MyEntity` :

```
public void MyMethod(MyEntity myEntity) { ... }
```

When I check the parameter myEntity, the **GUID** which is in **ID** is something different which I had sent from the Client side(front end/ajax call). Say for eg in my ajax call the stringified Json contained `"abcd1"` in property `_ID` & `ID`, but in WebApi's `POST` method parameter I get a new GUID in ID & _ID lets say `"xyz2"`. Why is this happening? My getter setters are written in a way that if there is a null in _ID then only new GUID will be generated otherwise previous one will be returned.

Also one more question. On **Ajax's POST** call when the WebApi controller receives the auto-deserialized stringified JSON data as an entity in `MyMethod`'s parameter `myEntity`, are the **getter methods** executed for the deserialization or **setter methods**?

Comment: Looks like the _ID is always null then. Did you check the request?

Comment: In my first cycle when I am populating List<MyEntity> , new GUIDs are generated in the List. This List of items is sent to the front end. Then on user's action an Ajax Post call is made, this time the request contains that GUID which was generated previously when I was populating the List<MyEntity>. I checked it through chrome's Network tab. When the request reaches the WebApi controller, a new GUID is now in ID & _ID. On the client side I had the old GUID, I double checked it.

Comment: When the object is constructed the field _ID is always null. You should put this logic of create a new ID at the constructor, not the propertie It self.